# How to pass valus selected from HTML Form?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, forms, http-post

I have a PHP file that contains two forms. Form1 (Intermediate) that has one text box and three dropdown lists as filters. Once I hit the submit button in Form1, the values are POST'ed to another PHP file for computation and Form2(ProductionForm) is displayed (which is hidden so far).

I've done this with the jQuery,  here is the code snippet:

```
  <script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#intermediate").submit(function() {
    /* AJAX calls and insertion into #productionForm */

        $.post("../c/ProductionSummaryFormCalculation.php", {
        Date: $('#datepicker').val(),
        ShiftId: $('#selectShift :selected').val(),
        Machine: $('#selectMachine :selected').val(),
        User: $('#selectUser :selected').val(),
    });

        $("#datepicker").prop("disabled", true);
        $("#selectShift").prop("disabled", true);
        $("#selectMachine").prop("disabled", true);
        $("#selectUser").prop("disabled", true);
    $("#productionForm").show();
        return false;
    });
});
```

I want the value computed from ProductionSummaryFormCalculation.php file and loaded into a text box in Form2.

When I use it in the following code it doesn't work:

```
    <input id="start_time_text" class="start_time_text" type="text" name="start_time_text" value="<?php echo $start_time; ?>">
```

Also, I want to send the values selected from both Form1 and Form2 to another PHP file through a POST method when I hit the submit button in Form2.

```
    $("#productionForm").submit(function() {
    /* AJAX calls and insertion into #productionForm */
        $.post("../c/ProductionSummaryForm2.php", {
        start_time: $('#start_time_text').val(),
        end_time: $('#end_time_text').val(),
        remarks: $('#Remarks').val()
    });
});
```

How can I achieve this; can someone help me out?

Comment: That should be $_POST['start_time'];

Comment: That's not working. moreover i'm not posting anything in ProductionSummaryFormCalculation.php.

Comment: how then is the user getting from form 1 to form 2?

Comment: Stop the default action of the form.. `$("#productionForm").submit(function(e) { e.preventDefault(); // Your code here`

Comment: @Dagon i'm using this in the jquery, hence the use is able to move from form 1 to form 2 ` $("#productionForm").show();`

Answer (score 0):

When you do $.post you can also put a function that gets executed when the submit is successful. 
http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/
After submitting the first form get the the php file to return to you whatever you want and add it to the desired textarea.

If this is a simple 2 step form you do not have to send the first form to a file and return the result. Just create 1 form that contains both divs, on the first submit hide 1 div show the other div and submit them both together.

Comment: Also as Sushanth suggested you should use
$("#productionForm").submit(function(e) { e.preventDefault();
to stop the form from submitting the first time

Comment: i have a jtable inside form2, hence i put both forms seperately. code rearranging is not possible right now. is there any ways to send both form1&2 selected values in POST method of submit click of form 2

Comment: when i add success function in jquery? i tried like this, `User: $('#selectUser :selected').val(),
   success:function(data){
     alert(data);
   }` but i get alert as undefined, once i click the submit button. i guess the alert is getting executed even before the computation takes place in php file. am i adding the success function correctly???

Comment: $.post("test.php", { name: "John", time: "2pm" },
   function(data) {
     alert("Data Loaded: " + data);
   });

Comment: In the link i gave you around 1/3 of the way down on the page you have plenty of examples.

Comment: should i echo the computed valued in the php file to get the data for the function???

Comment: Thanks a lot. U saved my day. i got the data. i have one more small doubt, how to use this data inside HTML form??? how can i access morethan one data from that php file??

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/21413/discussion-between-mihai-p-and-allen)